# GR examples in Python don't open a window with visualization

Tags: python, visualization, gr

I installed GR and its dependencies on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8.10 following instructions on https://gr-framework.org/python.html#installation. The first example:

```
from gr.pygr import mlab
mlab.plot(range(100), lambda x: x**2)
```

Doesn't create a window or terminal output. Any ideas what may be missing?

---

The plot shows when run in Jupyter. What is the way to plot from the terminal?